# When opening sidebar horizontally, text is momentarily oriented vertically

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript, chakra-ui

chakra ui and next.js.
When the sidebar is displayed, the text next to the icon momentarily becomes vertical.
The code is listed below.
I have also included the codepen url.

https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-matan-du82mv?file=/src/Sidebar.tsx:0-1975

```
import {
  Box,
  chakra,
  HStack,
  IconButton,
  Text,
  useColorModeValue,
  VStack
} from "@chakra-ui/react";
import * as React from "react";
import { FiFileText, FiMenu, FiSettings, FiUser } from "react-icons/fi";

interface SidebarItemProps {
  icon: JSX.Element;
  isOpen: boolean;
  label: string;
}

const SidebarItem: React.FC<SidebarItemProps> = ({ icon, isOpen, label }) => {
  const hoverColor = useColorModeValue("gray.600", "gray.300");

  return (
    <chakra.div
      role="group"
      _hover={{ bg: hoverColor }}
      transition="background-color 0.2s"
      borderRadius="md"
      w="100%"
    >
      <HStack alignItems="center" p={2} maxW="100%">
        <IconButton
          aria-label={label}
          icon={icon}
          size="sm"
          variant="ghost"
          _groupHover={{ bg: "transparent" }}
          boxSize={6}
        />
        <Text
          display={isOpen ? "flex" : "none"}
          alignItems="center"
          color="white"
          ml={2}
        >
          {label}
        </Text>
      </HStack>
    </chakra.div>
  );
};

export const Sidebar: React.FC = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleToggle = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };

  return (
    <Box
      as="nav"
      position="fixed"
      left="0"
      top="0"
      bg="black"
      h="100vh"
      w={isOpen ? "200px" : "78px"}
      transition={isOpen ? "width 0.3s" : ""}
    >
      <VStack align="start" p={4}>
        <IconButton
          aria-label="Toggle Menu"
          icon={<FiMenu />}
          onClick={handleToggle}
          mb={6}
          w="12"
        />

        <VStack w="100%" align="start" spacing={6}>
          <SidebarItem icon={<FiUser />} isOpen={isOpen} label="ユーザー" />
          <SidebarItem icon={<FiFileText />} isOpen={isOpen} label="投稿" />
          <SidebarItem icon={<FiSettings />} isOpen={isOpen} label="管理" />
        </VStack>
      </VStack>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

I tried adding flexDirection to Text, but it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this to you css file:

```
#text {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

and replace `<Sidebar />` this in the App.tsx file:

```
<div id="text"><Sidebar /></div>
```

Both these work together to both stop it from starting on a new line and overflowing to outside the sidebar.